# How to I fix this? f1026 file not found 'crt.dcu'

Tags: delphi

How can I fix this error?

I have this error when I compile the code. I have no idea what it means or how I can fix this.

[image: Screen shot of the error.]

Comment: You're missing a unit called crt in your project. You program seems to be for FreePascal because old Pascal compilers did not use `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` directives and FreePascal ships with unit crt, Delphi does not.

Comment: @TLama Or Delphi with a crt port. I just went along with the tag. I guess the real problem could just be that Aleem doesn't really know what this code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crt` is not part of the Delphi RTL. The original `crt` unit was part of Turbo Pascal and supports console mode operations. There are a variety of ports of `crt` to Windows. I don't have a good recommendation, but a websearch might lead you to a solution.

Now, do not be surprised if you need more work to get this code to compile. It would appear that you have not written the code yourself because if you had you would know all about `crt`. It's possible that this is old TP code that needs more porting. Or perhaps it is modern Delphi code that assumes a particular `crt` port. Or perhaps the code is intended for a different Pascal compiler, for instance FreePascal.

If you want more specific advice you would do well to know more about where the code originated. I would ask whoever gave you the code to tell you what the intended development environment is.

Comment: The code was given to me by the exam board. For my comp AQA exam however I cannot get it to run on my computer.

Comment: Is the exam board expecting you to use Delphi? Perhaps they expect you to use FreePascal?

Comment: @Aleem I guess you need to be clear as to what dev environment is required.